# XSD validation for multiple entries in a XML

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, saxon

I am using SAXON parser for XSD validation in Java. If we use a XML with single element it works fine. Even if we have multiple elements it works fine. But we are unable to identify which element failed and which passed. To be more clear, we have an XSD to validate a simple xml file with a root element  and the other elements within are `<person> <employment></employment></person>`. The  is repeatable element.I have an xml like below with errors.

```
<person>
<employment>correct elements inside</employment>
<employment>wrong elements inside </employment>
</person>
```

I am performing a XSD validation for above xml. It fails overall due to error in second `<employment>` entry. But what I need is to identify that first employment passed and second one failed.

How can I achieve this using SAXON?

Comment: Your XML and XSD code went poof, can you edit it in?

Comment: example xml : <person><emp></emp><emp></emp></person>  where <emp> is repeatable. So I want to identify which <emp> failed and which passed.

Comment: @BalachandarThangavel, please [update your Q.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32526891/edit), do not paste code that way in comments, **it is unreadable** and doesn't help anybody. Also, have a look at [mcve] to help us help you.

Comment: I updated your Q. Next time, click the buttons in the editor to format code as code and to prevent the XML to become invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you are running the validation: From the command line? from the JAXP validation API? From XSLT or XQuery? From the s9api API?

If you are running from the command line then all validation errors are output to System.err with location information about where they were found.

If you are running from an application (via any of the APIs) then errors are notified to an ErrorListener. The default ErrorListener behaves like the command line - it writes details to System.err. If it's a GUI application then you probably won't see this unless you redirect it to some window. Given what you say about your requirements, you would probably be advised to write your own ErrorListener that formats the output in the way you want it. Some of the APIs provide an option to supply a List object into which objects are written representing the validation errors found.

In the next release (9.7) we will have an option to produce all the validation errors in an XML report format.

MORE INFORMATION BASED ON YOUR RESPONSE:

I would recommend using SchemaValidator.setErrorListener() to set your own ErrorListener. The exception passed to the ErrorListener will typically be an instance of net.sf.saxon.type.ValidationException.

If you are validating an in-memory tree, then ValidationException.getNode() on this exception object should give you the node that's invalid, or perhaps the node where the invalidity was detected, which is not quite the same thing.

If you are validating a stream of events, e.g. a SAXSource, then ValidationException.getPath() should give you a path to the node in the form of a string, while ValidationException.getAbsolutePath() should give you a path in structured form.

Comment: I am using SAXON9 api to validate the file.

Comment: Thanks @Michael KAy .. we used the same and it is working fine